# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml, page-factory

The below code is failing in `homeSignInLink.click();` and giving error

```
"NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null
```

**Code**

```
public class LoginTest extends TestBase
{
    WebDriver driver;
    HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(driver);
     
    @Test
    public void login_check()
    {
        objHomePage.clickHomeSignInLink();
        objHomePage.clickRecruiterSignInLink();
    }
}

public class HomePage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='nav-link bold' and text()='Sign in']") WebElement homeSignInLink;   
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[text()='Recruiter sign in']") WebElement recruiterSignInLink;  

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
        //This initElements method will create all WebElements
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    } 
    public void clickHomeSignInLink()
    {   
        homeSignInLink.click();
    }
    public void clickRecruiterSignInLink()
    {
        recruiterSignInLink.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you provide and load a URL anywhere? Maybe the search context is `null` because no website has been loaded.

Comment: That's not the case. The search context is WebElement or WebDriver. Why is it null? Where do you initialize the WebDriver instance? You're passing driver to initElements - is it initialized somewhere?

Comment: no, I have not initialized the WebDriver instance. Where do I need to initialize? My testbase code
```
public class TestBase 
{
 WebDriver driver; 
 @BeforeTest
 public void setup()
 {
  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("https://stage.aviationjobsearch.com/");
 }
}
```

Comment: Please check your xpath is properly finding the element, in your developer tools. driver is unable to identify the element that is why it is returning the Null value

Answer (score 1):

Please use the same WebDriver instance from your TestBase class throughout all the scripts.
Ex., in LoginTest class remove the WebDriver declaration and modify the line:

```
HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(TestBase.driver);
```

Make the WebDriver instance as static in TestBase class.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver; You are freshly declaring hence its null.

public class LoginTest extends TestBase { //Comment this as you are already extending TestBase
// WebDriver driver;

//Also instead of mentioning driver //= new Chromedriver();
// in before //method..write it here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginStep {
public static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
LoginPom lp = new LoginPom(driver);

@Given("user navigate the login page")
public void user_navigate_the_login_page() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    //driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://letcode.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    lp.Loginbutton().click();
```

webdriver driver = new chromedriver();
its working for me you have to initialize the browser first before entering into the steps